# Is there electromagnetic abrasion / erosion?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

When a sensor registers electromagnetic radiation, such as that used for the transmission of communication like light or radio waves, does this radiation "abrade" or "erode" the material of the sensor?

Are there any traces of the received radiation that can be detected, even if only theoretically?

An example from a biological background would be that high energy light (such as that in the UV range) destroys the pigments in the eyes, which is why animals that live longer than a few years cannot see in the UV range. Maybe something similar happens with man made sensors for different wavelengths of electromagnetic radiation.

Comment: Physical erosion usually usually doesn't happen unless the power is extremely high or the wavelength is extremely short. What do you mean by "are there traces of radiation that can be detected"? We detect radiation all the time with our eyes.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus See the example given in my edit. Traces in the sensor, caused by the radiation destroying or changing the sensor (photographic film is a sensor that is being changed by the radiation it is made to receive).

Comment: I already addressed your edit in my earlier comment.

Comment: No, you said: "We detect radiation all the time with our eyes." What I mean is: Can we detect the erosion effects of radiation on the man-made sensors (like antennas, CMS etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

CCD type sensors can be damaged by radiation, resulting in so-called hot pixels. [This handbook](http://www.stsci.edu/hst/acs/documents/handbooks/cycle19/c04_detector4.html) says "Warm and hot pixels accumulate as a function of time on orbit. Defects responsible for elevated dark rate are created continuously as a result of the ongoing displacement damage on orbit."

Now space is a pretty extreme environment, and the radiation is probably due to high energy protons more than very intense light.

But in any case, semi-conductors do degrade over time, as defects in the lattice can occur for thermal reasons or due to radiation damage, creating charge carriers where there shouldn't be any, and furthermore ions diffuse where they shouldn't. Just google for damage+uv+ccd or damage+uv+cmos or the like.